# Google in-app-purchases subscriptions return error : "invalid value"

Tags: google-api, in-app-subscription, google-play-developer-api, androidpublisher

I need to check the monthly renewals of user subscriptions but I keep getting the following error when querying:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid Value",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Invalid Value",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I checked some possible values ​​that could be wrong.
Using the androidpublisher api I can consult information about which subscriptions I have available, which in my understanding means that I have the following correct values:
1-access token,refresh token,scope
2-package Name
3-subscription ID

example:https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/test.test.test/subscriptions/123456789
(return correct information)

Some errors that I may have are the use of an old endpoint (which I think is unlikely since I tested with
1-several endpoints that I found on the internet over the course of weeks ...but for now i trying with these)
[https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D)
OR
[https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/%7Btoken%7D)

2-The purchase token, (something like "GPA.11111-1111-11111-11111") could for some reason be invalid information.

an example of how I'm assembling the request in case of bad formatting is this... a curl version of what I'm doing;

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/ab.abc.abcde/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionExample/tokens/GPA.123123-1233-1233-12323